# ::-webkit-datetime-edit not working on safari web desktop browser

Tags: datetime, safari, webkit

I use the ::-webkit-datetime-edit CSS property in order to control the appearance of a date input field for webkit browsers.

But not working on safari web browser,

Here is my code:`<input type="date">`

```
input[type="date"]::-webkit-datetime-edit, input[type="date"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, input[type="date"]::-webkit-clear-button {
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  line-height:normal;
}

input[type="date"]::-webkit-datetime-edit-year-field{
  position: absolute;
  border-left:0.2px solid #8c8c8c;
  padding: 2px;
  color:#8d8a8a;
  left: 56px;
}

input[type="date"]::-webkit-datetime-edit-month-field{
  position: absolute !important;
  padding: 2px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  color:#8d8a8a;
  left: 0px;
}

input[type="date"]::-webkit-datetime-edit-day-field{
  position: absolute !important;
  border-left:0.2px solid #8c8c8c;
  color:#8d8a8a;
  padding: 2px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  left: 26px;
}
```

Here is a codepen: https://codepen.io/Sanket-Thakkar-the-solid/pen/VwVKKjG

Pls help me how can i fix this bug on safari desktop. working on all other browser.